# Swift 3: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: json, swift3

I am trying to parse JSON in swift 3 below is my JSON file. And try to get in a array of class which i have declared. But getting error: fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type.

```
{
"Headers": [
            {
            "headerName": "Home",
            "sortByNo" : 1,
            "headerImageName": "header0",
            "viewCotrollerName": "InitialViewController"

            },
            {
            "headerName": "About",
            "sortByNo" : 2,
            "headerImageName": "header1",
            "viewCotrollerName": ""
            },
            {
            "headerName": "Timing",
            "sortByNo" : 3,
            "headerImageName": "header3",
            "viewCotrollerName": "TimingViewController"
            }
        ]
}


  // Class Type 
class JsonObjectClass {

var headerName = ""
var sortByNo = ""
var headerImageName = ""
var viewControllerName = ""

}

var array = [JsonObjectClass]() // my array of class type

//JSON Parsing Code
 func parseLocalFile() {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HeaderFileD", withExtension: "json")
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

        array = jsonData.object(forKey: "Headers") as! [JsonObjectClass]

   // I am getting error here "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"         
        for arr in array {
            print(arr)

        }

    } catch {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array or dictionary to a custom class directly.
You need to map the array by creating instances of your class.

I changed the class to a struct to get the member-wise initializer. By the way, the value for key `sortByNo` is an `Int`

```
struct JsonObjectClass {
  var headerName = ""
  var sortByNo = 0
  var headerImageName = ""
  var viewControllerName = ""
}

var array = [JsonObjectClass]() // my array of class type

//JSON Parsing Code
func parseLocalFile() {

  guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HeaderFileD", withExtension: "json") else { return }

  do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    let jsonArray = jsonData["Headers"] as! [[String:Any]]
    array = jsonArray.map { JsonObjectClass(headerName: $0["headerName"] as! String,
                                   sortByNo: $0["sortByNo"] as! Int,
                                   headerImageName: $0["headerImageName"] as! String,
                                   viewControllerName: $0["viewCotrollerName"] as! String)}

    for arr in array {
      print(arr)
    }

  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

PS: Consider the typo `viewControllerName` vs `viewCotrollerName`